# Stream mp4 video via ffmpeg and rtmp using red5

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtmp, red5

I need to stream mp4 video file via FFMPEG and stream the output to RED5 using RTMP protocol. I am using the following command to do this. It's encoding perfectly, but it does not play when I embed with jwplayer.

```
ffmpeg -i http://xxxxxx.com/adv.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://xxxxxxx/live/stream1
```

it's given the following result:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/adv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013052900
  Duration: 00:04:50.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 912 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1920x360 [PAR 847:1920 DAR 847:360], 795 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 11025 Hz, stereo, s16, 116 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxx/live/stream1':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1920x360 [PAR 847:1920 DAR 847:360], q=2-31, 795 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libvo_aacenc, 11025 Hz, stereo, 116 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-14 11:57:33
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame= 7266 fps=563 q=-1.0 Lsize=   32544kB time=290.64 bitrate= 917.3kbits/s    
video:28220kB audio:4130kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.601155%
```

After this i embed the RTMP url to my jwplayer

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'http://xxxxxxxxxx/tools/js/jwplayer.flash.swf',
            'stretching': 'exactfit',
            'type': 'rtmp',     
            'file':'stream1',
            'autostart': 'true',            
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'streamer':'rtmp://xxxxxxxx/live/', 

            'width': '889',
            'height': '410',

            });
            </script>
```

After done this my player show the following error

> ```
> Error loading stream
> Could not connect to the server
> ```

how can i solve this and stream like live stream....???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command. This is the command i usually use to stream a video file as a live stream

> ffmpeg -re -i localFile.mp4 -c copy -f flv
>   rtmp://server/live/streamName

The -re option tells FFmpeg to read the input file in realtime and not in the standard as-fast-as-possible manner. With -c copy (alias -acodec copy -vcodec copy ) I’m telling FFmpeg to copy the essences of the input file without transcoding, then to package them in an FLV container (-f flv) and send the final bitstream to an rtmp destination (rtmp://server/live/streamName).

The JWplayer source is as follows

```
<html>
<head><title>TEST PLAYER</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
file: "rtmp://[ip-address]/live/streamname",
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure the jwplayer.js and player.swf are in the correct locations.

Comment: how can i embed with jwplayer ???

Comment: which version of jwplayer u using?

Comment: jwplayer 6.0 above

Comment: your above ffmpeg code return this error                       `Unrecognized option 'c'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c'`

Comment: No error here. Check command once more. Try changing the order of options

Comment: how can i add multi input file

Comment: This is the command i used

ffmpeg -re -i /usr/local/content/sample.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.34:1935/live/test

Comment: my friend i said mulit input like following syntax   `ffmpeg -re i- inputfile1.mp4,inputfile2.mp4,inputfile3.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://xxxxx/live/test`   like this how can i command

Comment: I think you cant add multiple files like this using this command.First try the command i said. Its applicable for a single file.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Comment: can we use vlc to ffmpeg and rtmp for getting multiple file ?

Comment: I have nt worked with vlc much. I guess you can open multiple instances of FFMpeg. I mean just execute the commands in different tabs for different files. But the system load will go up. Anyways try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12709/discussion-between-unnikrishnan-and-tamil-arvu)